# Combinatorics question. Where am I wrong in my reasoning?

Tags: combinatorics

*A 5-card poker hand is said to be a full house if it consists of 3 cards of the same denomination and 2 other cards of the same denomination (of course, different from the first denomination). Thus, one kind of full house is three of a kind plus a pair. What is the probability that one is dealt a full house?*

I solved this as follows: 
Sample space is 52 choose 5

For the first card out of 5 we have 13x4 possible choices (any card);
For second 3 choices (3 different suits of same card);
For third 2 choice (2 different suits of same card);
For fourth we have (13 x 4 - 4); 
For fifth we have 3 choices;

thus: 
( 13 x 4 x 3 x 2 x (13 x 4 - 4) x 3 ) / (52 choose 5)

The answer is approx : 0.017

While the solution in book :
[image]

Where was I wrong in my reasoning?

Thanks

Comment: For second card you have actually 51 choices because what ever card it is you can still get a full house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong in your reasoning is that in your description (first we draw a card, then we draw a card of the same denomination, etc) the order is fixed. That is, you are not considering that the 5 cards of a full house can be drawn in *any* order.

There are basically two ways to solve the problem:

1. Combinations. There are $\binom{52}5$ deals. How many of these deals are a full house? First: choose the denomination of the three: 13 possibilities. Then, choose the denomination of the pair: 12 possibilities. Now choose the cards of the three: $\binom{4}3$ possibilities. Now, choose the two other cards: $\binom{4}2$ possibilities.
   Then, the probability is
   $$\frac{13\cdot12\cdot\binom{4}3\binom{4}2}{\binom{52}5}$$
2. Variations. There are $52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48$ deals. Now, we are considering that two deals are different if the cards were drawn in a different order, so there are *much more* deals. Namely, $5!=120$ times more. Now you can count your way. The probability is
   $$120\cdot \frac{52\cdot3\cdot2\cdot48\cdot3}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48}$$

You can check that they are, in fact, the same number.

Another way is the following:

- The probability for the first card is $1$, because no matter which card is, the full house can be achieved.
- The probaility of that the second card is of the same kind as first is $3/51$, and the pro. of that the third card is also the same kind is $2/50$
- The pro. of that the four card is *not* of the same kind as the former cards is $48/49$, and the probability of that the last card is the same kind as fourth is $3/48$

Then, the probability of drawing a full house, drawing the three and after the pair is
$$p=\frac{52}{52}\frac{3}{51}\frac{2}{50}\frac{48}{49}\frac{3}{48}$$

But since the cards of the full house can be drawn at any order, we must multiply by $120$.

Comment: Despite the assertion, these 3 methods do not evaluate to the same number.  The combinations method is about 0.001441, which matches the correct answer according to other sources.  The variations method and third method are easily seen to be identical, and are about 0.017287.

Comment: Correct answer should be
$$
\frac{{5\choose 3} \cdot 52 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 48 \cdot 3 }{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48}.
$$
That is, there is not $5!$ more deals when considering order but only ${5 \choose 3}$ more.